# What sense in DataType.Phone?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

DataAnnotation of ASP.NET MVC has DataType.Phone value. I.e.

```
    [Display(Name = "Coordinator Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string CoordinatorPhone { get; set; }
```

But what sense in it? It generates code:

```
<input class="form-control" id="SupervisorPhone" name="SupervisorPhone" type="text" value="">
```

Logically, it should generate type="phone", but it does not do it.

I have to add regular expression anyway:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. If I change in View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupervisorPhone)
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupervisorPhone)
```

it generates

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Entered phone format is not valid."... type="tel" value="">
```

(with type="tel")